# Make one table-cell fill remaining space while other take space by content

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="left-tabs tabs-group">
        <li>some</li>
        <li>content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="middle-tabs tabs-group">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-tabs">
        <li>another</li>
        <li>content</li>
    </ul>
</div>


.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.right-tabs {
  float: right;
}

.tabs-group {
  float: left;
}
```

Is it possible so that `left-tabs` and `right-tabs` take width by their content, and `middle-tabs` stretch to fill the remaining space? Is it possible with tables or without?
Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KOLYq71ZcLhlcjWgZkkF?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as long as content is not larger than the container.

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
}
ul{
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
.left-tabs{
    background:blue;
    color:#FFF;
}
.right-tabs {
    background:red;
    color:#FFF;
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="left-tabs">
        <li>some</li>
        <li>content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-tabs">
        <li>another</li>
        <li>content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="left-tabs">
        <li>some</li>
        <li>content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>content</li>
        <li>this is a very long content that is aligned</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-tabs">
        <li>another</li>
        <li>content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In this case, as seen in the example above, the desired design would not work anymore.

**EDIT**: You are right. This is a more "ugly" way to solve the issue, but it also have the following bug: the very long text in the middle tabs is hidden. If you want, you can solve it with **overflow:scroll**, but it isn't very good looking.

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
}
li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
.left-tabs {
  background: blue;
}
.middle-tabs {
  background: green;
  float: none;
}
.right-tabs {
  background: red;
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="left-tabs">
    <li>some</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="middle-tabs">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right-tabs">
    <li>another</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="left-tabs">
    <li>some</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="middle-tabs">
    <li>content</li>
    <li>this is a very long content that is aligned</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right-tabs">
    <li>another</li>
    <li>content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in your example the middle `ul` doesn't occupy all space, add background to it and you'll see yourself

Comment: You were right, the first time I didn't really answer. So I have made an edit. For more issues, comment.

Comment: Now it looks like it's occupying the remaining space, but it's actually going beyond the `another content` block. Check it's width